# Mysterious star operation in Silverman's "A Survey of the Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves"

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves

I am reading Silverman's article "A Survey of the Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves", which is published in *Modular Forms and Fermat's Last Theorem*. The article is (partly) accessible through [this Google Books link](https://books.google.ca/books?id=jD3TBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA17&lpg=PA17&dq=%22a+survey+of+the+arithmetic+theory+of+elliptic+curves%22&source=bl&ots=Edq88vR6Ko&sig=GvvKomaxnJCz2Tt6x-8EnRevJNs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi3gKbroJXYAhXpz4MKHZB4A4cQ6AEIMzAD#v=onepage&q&f=false).

The article uses a star notation I'm not familiar with. There are two particular cases I have in mind. First, speaking about an elliptic curve $E$ on page 18, Silverman writes:

> Further, for any point $Q \in E$, there is the *translation-by-*$Q$ map
>   $$\tau_Q : E \to E, \tau_Q(P) = P+Q.$$
>
> Riemann-Roch tells us that an elliptic curve has a unique holomorphic
>   differential (up to scalar). On the Weierstrass equations (1) and (2)
>   it is given by
>
> $$\omega_E = \frac{dx}{2y+a_1x+a_3} \ \ \text{ and } \ \ \omega_E = \frac{dx}{2y} \ \ \text{ respectively.}$$
>
> The uniqueness of $\omega_E$ implies that it is translation invariant,
>   $$\tau_Q^{*}(\omega_E) = \omega_E \ \ \text{for all } Q \in E.$$

I do not know what $\tau_Q^{*}$ means here.

Later, in defining the Weil pairing on the bottom of page 21 (unfortunately not accessible through Google Books), Silverman writes:

> Let $S,T \in E[m]$. Choose a function $g$ on $E$ whose divisor satisfies
>   $$\text{div}(g) = [m]^{*}(T) - [m]^{*}(O).$$

I know that $[m]P$ is the $m$-fold sum of $P$ with itself (if $m > 0$), but I don't know how $[m]^{*}$ is defined.

Comment: $\tau_Q(P) =(R)$ where $R=P+Q$ is the addition in the group law of $E$. A differential $\omega$ acts on curves $\gamma \subset E$ by $\gamma \mapsto \int_\gamma \omega$ (well-defined modulo closed-loops)
and $\tau_Q$ acts naturally on curves  $\subset E$ by translation.
Then $\tau_Q^*(\omega)$ is the differential such that $\int_\gamma \tau_Q^*(\omega)=\int_{\tau_{-Q}(\gamma)}\omega$. In a quite similar way (pullback of operator along morphism) in the divisor group of $E$ : $[m]^* (P)$ is the divisor of degree one $R$ where $R = \underbrace{P+\ldots+P}_m$ in the group law.

Comment: Thanks! That clarifies it, especially in conjunction with hunter's more general answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f: X \to Y$ is a morphism, where $X$ and $Y$ are objects of some category, and $F$ is a contravariant functor from that category to another one, we write $f^*$ for the induced morphism $F(Y) \to F(X)$. (If $F$ is contravariant, we write $f_*:F(X) \to F(Y)$.)

Comment: Dropping the term "pullback" somewhere would help in googling for more information ;-)

Comment: ha sorry :)   OP: in your cases the functors are respectively $\Omega$ and div which take varieties to abelian groups and what it does to function is the pullback opertion on differential forms resp. divisors